# Python - sklearn - Value Error: empty vocabulary

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to emulate a project previously done and I am running into trouble with a CountVectorizer function.  Below is the code that pertains to the issue.

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk, textmining, pprint, re, os.path 
#import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import fileinput

list = ["carmilla.txt", "pirate-caribbee.txt", "rider-sage.txt"]

for l in list:
    f = open(l)
    raw1 = f.read()
    print "<-----Here goes nothing"
    head = raw1[:680]
    foot = raw1[157560:176380]
    content = raw1[680:157560]
    print "Done---->"

content=[re.sub(r'[\']', '', text)for text in content]
content=[re.sub(r'[^\w\s\.]', ' ', text) for text in content]

print content

propernouns = []
for story in content:
    propernouns = propernouns+re.findall(r'Mr.[\s][\w]+', story)
    propernouns = propernouns+re.findall(r'Mrs.[\s][\w]+', story)
    propernouns = propernouns+re.findall(r'Ms.[\s][\w]+', story)
    propernouns = propernouns+re.findall(r'Miss.[\s][\w]+', story)

propernouns = set(propernouns)
print "\nNumber of proper nouns: " + str(len(propernouns))
print "\nExamples from our list of proper nouns: "+str(sorted(propernouns))

#Strip all of the above out of text
for word in propernouns:
    content = [re.sub(" "+word+" "," ",story) for story in content]

import string
content = [story.translate(string.maketrans("",""), "_.0123456789")]

print "\n[2] -----Carmilla Text-----"
print content

#Prepare a list of stopwords
f1 = open('stopwords.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('stopwords2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

stopfile = open('stopwords2.txt')

print "Examples of stopwords: "
print stopfile.read()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopfile , min_df=1)
stories_tdm = cv.fit_transform(content).toarray()
```

Executing this does not finish, and I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mnate_000\workspace\de.vogella.python.third\src\TestFile_EDIT.py", line 84, in <module>
    stories_tdm = cv.fit_transform(content).toarray()
  File "C:\Users\mnate_000\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 780, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
  File "C:\Users\mnate_000\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 727, in _count_vocab
    raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
**ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words**
```

I'm not sure where to go because I've tried replacing "content" with another file as a test and it identifies that I am not using a stopfile.. I can't seem to get it to operate properly.  Has anyone else ran into this issue?  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to close your files properly. `f.close()` is nowhere, `f2.close()` shouldn't be indented, and neither should `f1.close()`

I think this might fix your problem.

```
for l in list:
    f = open(l)
    raw1 = f.read()
    print "<-----Here goes nothing"
    head = raw1[:680]
    foot = raw1[157560:176380]
    content = raw1[680:157560]
    print "Done---->"
    f.close()
```

...

```
#Prepare a list of stopwords
f1 = open('stopwords.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('stopwords2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

**EDIT**
I see two more issues:

One is this:
    content = [story.translate(string.maketrans("",""), "_.0123456789")]

No `story` variable exists at this indentation level, so please clarify that.

The other issue is that `stop_words` may either be a `string`, a `list` or `None`. In the case of `string`, the only supported value is `'english'`. However, in your case you pass a file handle:

```
stopfile = open('stopwords2.txt')
#...
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopfile , min_df=1)
```

What you should do is turn all the text in `stopfile` into a list of strings.
Replace this:

```
#Prepare a list of stopwords
f1 = open('stopwords.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('stopwords2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

stopfile = open('stopwords2.txt')

print "Examples of stopwords: "
print stopfile.read()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopfile , min_df=1)
```

With this:

```
#Prepare a list of stopwords
f1 = open('stopwords.txt', 'r')
stoplist = []
for line in f1:
    nextlist = line.replace('\n', ' ').split()
    stoplist.extend(nextlist)
f1.close()

print "Examples of stopwords: "
print stoplist


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stoplist, min_df=1)
```

Comment: I added in the `f.close()` and adjusted the indents thanks for catching both of those.  However, I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: @Dillon: Can you tell me what `content = [story.translate(string.maketrans("",""), "_.0123456789")]` is supposed to do? That is, where does the `story` variable come from? I don't see a `story` variable at this indentation level.

Comment: the `content=[...` code you were talking about was using a story variable that was created earlier with the "propernouns" array.  I took it out in my program and no difference was made.  In the original project it was in there and worked fine though.  I suppose `content` isnt getting initialized correctly to be used in the `cv.fit_transform` function.

Comment: @Dillon: You shouldn't reuse the variable as a local one inside of loops, then. Also, did you address the other thing I suggested (Preparing a list of stopwords)?

Comment: Yes I have, I've included that in my last step. I think what I may do is try another method of creating vectors from strings.